# Hide a window until it's needed again

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on this WPF project. The main window has 8 buttons which all open another window. What I'd like to do, is when the user clicks one of the buttons, the main window is hidden(not closed), and the secondary window is open. Now, when the secondary window is closed, I want to unhide my main window. Here's the code I've got.

```
public WndwProjectSetup(Window mainWindow)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _mainWindow = mainWindow;
    _mainWindow.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; // hides main window
}

private void WindowClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    _mainWindow.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; // unhides main window

    Close(); // close Project Setup window
}
```

This seems simple and straight forward to me. Yet, I get this error:

```
Cannot set Visibility to Visible or call Show, ShowDialog, Close, or 
WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle while a Window is closing.
```

My question is, why is this not acceptable? What do I need to look into to figure out how to do this?

Comment: Have you tried to comment the `Close()` operation inside `WindowClosing`? It seems not logical to do Close inside `WindowClosing`. It is like `closingception`

Comment: As a workaround put on your main form a tabControl, put 2 tabItmes, on each tab define desired layout, then operate with the Visible property of each tab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to call `Close`, it's already closing. (If anything you can cancel it by setting `e.Cancel` to `true`)