# WPF dialogBox Don't close the application

Tags: c#, wpf

I made a custom dialog box in WPF. I want , when the user clicks X the dialogBox will be opened, if he wants to exit he should click "yes", if not he should click "no".

```
    static public bool? close;
    private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        WindowClose windowClose = new WindowClose();
        windowClose.ShowDialog();
        close = windowClose.DialogResult;
        if (close == true)
        {
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }

        else
        {
            //DONT CLOSE THE APPLICATION AND SHOW THE CURRENT WINDOW
        }

    }
```

the code of the dialog box:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = true;
        this.Close();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = false;
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Set the `CancelEventArgs.Cancel` to `true` to prevent the dialog from closing. See answer #2 here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23613694/wpf-mvvm-cancel-window-closing-event/23614197#23614197

Comment: OK, I fount how to... I added: e.Cancel = true;
                this.Show();

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide a window until it's needed again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16567818/hide-a-window-until-its-needed-again)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it works differently in WPF, but in standard winforms in the code for the dialog box you'd set (for example) the DialogResult to DialogResult.OK (yes) and DialogResult.Cancel (no). You wouldn't need to close the form as this is done automatically when you set the DialogResult

Then in the main form you'd have

```
If (windowClose.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK
{
    Application.Current.Shutdown();
}
else
{
    //DONT CLOSE THE APPLICATION AND SHOW THE CURRENT WINDOW
}
```